# Is it good practice to directly call REST endpoint (method) from another REST endpoint of same controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I have one Spring REST controller class which has multiple endpoints. Is it good practice to directly call endpoint method from another endpoint?

I have googled it but did not find any answer to what is the good practice to handle this.

```
@RestController
public class DataContoller {

    @GetMapping("/dataA/{param}")
    public ResponseEntity getDataA(@PathVariable String param) {
     // logic to fetch data A
     return ResponseEntity.ok("A");  
    }

    @GetMapping("/dataB/{param}")
    public ResponseEntity getDataB(@PathVariable String param) {
     ResponseEntity response = getDataA("test");
     String result = response.getBody();
     return ResponseEntity.ok("B" + result);  
    }

}
```

In principal it works as it is just a method call from another method but I would like to know if that's a good practice or not. And if its not good practice then what is the ideal way to do it. One option is using RestTemplate. Is that the only option?

Comment: No it isn't. And i think it makes no sence. This what you are trying to do means, that you have two endpoints wich do the same thing

Comment: Hi Jens - Above code is probably not a good example but I am stuck with real situation where one end point is required to call another as it needs that data to proceed.

Comment: You should handle it on service layer

Comment: If two methods need to fetch the same data, the same way, then extract a method `fetchData`, put it in a service, inject the service in your controller, and call the method from the two controller methods. methodA doesn't need the ResponseEntity created by method B. They just need to fetch the same data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that bad, but it's not good either.

The problem is that a direct call `getDataA("test")` skips everything that normally precedes this controller's method: security checks, validation, filtering, logging, mapping, or any other kind of data manipulation.

It introduces instability: you are not sure what data comes in, and where it really came from. Did it come from my internal method, or was it an HTTP call?

A very simple advise would be to have a service method `getDataA` and call it from both controller's methods. However, as you already noticed, it doesn't fully replace an HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your comment. Even if I move logic to service layer and call service layer method instead of controller that would still mean that I am skipping security check, validation, logging or mapping. My point is it just look ugly calling one controller method from another other than that if one method is only interested in result of another then why not call controller method directly.

Comment: I agree with what you say midway through your comment, but I do not agree with this part `skips everything that normally precedes this controller's method: security checks, validation, filtering, logging, mapping, or any other kind of data manipulation`. Ideally controllers should only handle the delegation of the http request over to the service level and not perform any other function. There are other components that serve this purpose.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex we are saying the same thing. By "everything" I mean "any other component" - I am strongly against placing the security/filtering/etc responsibility on a controller.